# Remote validation not working properly on IE?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I am working on MVC5 where i check form field to restrict with duplicate name. If one record is exist in DB then the duplicate name can not be entered. This functionality is working accurate on chrome and firefox but on IE it's not working. Here is my fucntion:

```
public JsonResult CheckDuplicateName(string Name, byte Id) {    
    bool shouldAddUpdate = !(new NameService().CheckDuplicateName(Name, Id));                             
    return Json(shouldAddUpdate, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

This function is working correctly. As i said the remote validation is working right on chrome and Firefox but not on IE. I debugged on chrome and this function is hit each time when i add new one. At the same time when i debugged on IE, this function is hit only first time when i add new one. Second time when i add the record this function is not hitting. What is the problem?

Comment: The code you have shown is server code and has nothing to do with which browser your using. What do you mean _"is hit only first time when i add new one"_ Add  a new what? and how are you adding it. Show the relevant view code.

Comment: There is a text field where i add record to the DB.

Comment: If i add one record like "ABC" and then again i save "ABC" then it it means the duplicate record is entered.

Comment: Show the relevant code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]` before your function call.

For further details, please see [here](http://azadehkhojandi.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-solve-mvc-remote-validation.html)